# Import arcpy crashes on ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, installation

I have installed ArcGIS Server 10.4 on Windows Server 2008 R2. I am intending to run standalone Python scripts. However when I tried to run the Python scripts, it crashed after importing arcpy.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstall multiple times but it still crashes.
I have only 1 installation (ArcGIS Server 10.4 (64-bit Python), no Desktop).
I have added environment path for PYTHONPATH and .pth file as well.

I would like to understand in my case why it crashes despite only having one version of Python and is there a way to solve the crashing?

Comment: Can you please go to the location: C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4, launch the python.exe in the folder and try importing arcpy there.

Comment: I have tried the python.exe from the location: C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4. It crashes with the error kernelbase.dll

Comment: Check environmental variables to make sure that the path to your python install is there under Path.

Comment: i have added the environment variables of Python into PATH
PATH=C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\scripts

it still crashes even if i add this path on windows